# Output Range same as input range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have some history working with VBA, but can't seem to find the solution to this problem.  I found an iteration process to select a cell, do a process, and then select the next cell and do the process again, until NULL.  I am having a problem outputting each of the processes solutions into the next column. Here is what I have:

```
Sub Name ()

Dim X As Integer
Dim MyString as String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
NumRows = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("D2").Select
For X = 1 To NumRows
    MyString = ActiveCell.Value
    MyString = Right(MyString, Len(MyString)-6)
    Range("I2 to I#").Value = MyString
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
Next X

End Sub
```

`Range("I2 to I#").Value = MyString` is the line that I need help with.  I need it to increment to I3, I4, I5, etc. until it reaches NumRows count.

Comment: Please read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Also avoid `integer` variables, the value you might want to store can be bigger than `integer` can hold.

Comment: Is using "select" the problem?

Comment: So Double would be better?

Comment: Use Long @Zman3. And using `Select` and `Activate` is inviting a lot of trouble into your code

Comment: Adding to @JvdV's comment - when you declare an `Integer` in the newer versions of VBA, it *actually* declares the memory for a `Long`, but locks the rest out (so every `Integer` effectively wastes memory).  There is no advantage to ever using `Integer` instead of `Long` - it is mostly only left in for backwards compatibility.  Writing new code, always `Dim yourVariable As Long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Cells the best way to loop through them is `For Each Cell in Range` so taking this and as comments told you to avoid selecting, this should help you:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Name()

    Dim C As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your working sheet name
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column D
        Set MyRange = .Range("D2:D" & LastRow) 'declare your working range
        For Each C In MyRange
            If Not C = vbNullString Then .Cells(C.Row, "I") = Right(C, Len(C) - 6)
        Next C
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  This works great!  Could you please explain how the "&" works?

Comment: Its for concatenate `"Hello" & "World"` = `HelloWorld`. `"D2:D" & LastRow` = `"D2:D100"`(if `LastRow = 100`). Works on Excel the same way it does on VBA.

Comment: It's worth noting the difference in determining the last row here. OP's method will find the last non-blank cell in a column, while Damian's method will find the true last filled cell in a column, not taking any blank intermediate cells into account

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why couldn't you have "D2:DLastRow"?

Comment: VBA process the variables, for vba `LastRow = 100`, but `"D2:DLastRow"` = `"D2:DLastRow"`. Anything between double quotes means a `String` and vba won't process the variable `LastRow`, instead it will try to process the whole string causing error.

Comment: @TimStack and about your comment, I wanted to set the last row with data because there could be blank cells in between (maybe not, but I don't know that) so this code will loop through the last row and ignore the blank cells in between.

Comment: Yes @Damian, that's what I explained in my comment. Just valuable information for OP, I am sure you know the difference between `End(xlUp)` and `End(xlDown)`

Comment: I wanted to test your claim that a `For each` loop would be for the best, so I compared it against a `For to` loop. Each method did 3 million iterations, spread over 6 separate loops of 500'000 rows. The `For each` method averaged at `2.05 seconds`, the `For to` method at `2.28 seconds`. So, the `For each` method is on average `11.2%` faster, when going through and populating a range of cells. Quite interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is `Do Until`. You could use this method if you dont have empty cells in the middle of your data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim StartingPoint As Long

    StartingPoint = 2 'Set the line to begin

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the worksheet

        Do Until .Cells(StartingPoint, "D").Value = "" 'Repeat the process until you find empty cell

           .Cells(StartingPoint, "I").Value = Right(.Cells(StartingPoint, "D").Value, Len(.Cells(StartingPoint, "D").Value) - 6)

           StartingPoint = StartingPoint + 1

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```