# Loop through the range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a simple loop through the range (say column A range("A5:A15")) if there is a blank cell within that range I need the entire row/rows associated with the blank cell/cells to be hidden.

I was thinking of something like this to accommodate various ranges but get "type Mismatch" error. Any reasons why

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Variant, ar As Variant
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range

    Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Range

      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

      'Set MyArray = rng


       Set MyArray(1) = Range("O8:O17")
       Set MyArray(2) = Range("O55:O64")
       Set MyArray(3) = Range("G37:G46")
       Set MyArray(4) = Range("G89:G98")


        'ar = Array(Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4)

        'Set rng = .Range("O8:O17")

        For Each cell In MyArray

            If Len(cell.Value) < 1 Then

               cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? If Yes can you paste the code also.

Comment: @Mikku yes I did any suggestions here ?

Comment: Check the New Answer Added Below in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478651/5720144)

Comment: @Mikku you are a star It works like a magic! Never crossed ny mind to apply LBound to UBound

Comment: Well, now you can add more ranges to it if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something Like this:

You can put it in a subject:

```
For Each cell In Range("A5:A15")

    If Len(cell.Value) < 1 Then

        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If

Next
For Each cell In Range("A40:A55")

    If Len(cell.Value) < 1 Then

        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If

Next
```

---

New Answer :

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Variant, ar As Variant
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range

Dim MyArray(1 To 4) As Range

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

  'Set MyArray = rng


   Set MyArray(1) = Range("O8:O17")
   Set MyArray(2) = Range("O55:O64")
   Set MyArray(3) = Range("G37:G46")
   Set MyArray(4) = Range("G89:G98")


    'ar = Array(Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4)

    'Set rng = .Range("O8:O17")
Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)

            For Each cell In MyArray(i)

             If Len(cell.Value) < 1 Then

               cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

            End If

        Next

    Next

End With
```

Comment: Mikku a better apporach would be `If cell = vbNullString`

Comment: @Damian [checking the string length is actually faster](https://web.archive.org/web/20140712133312/http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/len-vs-blank-strings-vs-vbnullstring/), although unlikely to be noticeable

Comment: @Damian ... I think there are many ways for this. But yeah always to prefer the faster one.

Comment: @accurist ... Great! Accept the answer if it worked fine.

Comment: Just did. Great help Thank you. Just a quick question. Say I have more that one range to loop through. ("A5:A15 & "A40:A45") would it be possible to join those ranges together in above code ?

Comment: Simply you can copy paste the code once more in the same module and change its range for the second part. Now when you will run your code, it will work on both ranges

Comment: @accurist .. Edited the answer :)

Comment: yes I appreciate that but would it be possible to apply many different ranges in above code rather then repeat the code for each range ?

Comment: Yes if you can find a pattern that connects each Range.

Comment: @TimStack Do you think it is possible to apply all those different ranges in one code. If so how can I get about this I still get "Type Mismatch" error on the code above

Comment: @accurist I've edited my code conform your request.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Option Explicit
Sub youcouldhaveatleasttriedtodosomethingyourself()

Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, c As Range, target As Range

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)
    Set r1 = .Range("A1:A54")
    Set r2 = .Range("F3:F32")

    Set target = Application.Union(r1, r2) 
    For Each area In target.Areas
        For Each c In area
            If c.Value = vbNullString Then .Rows(c.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Next c
    Next area
End With

End Sub
```

Please note that I now have set two exemplifying ranges. You can always add more range variables to the Union function.

Comment: Tim, `For Each` works faster on sheets than `For i`

Comment: @Damian yes... [didn't we talk about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336838/10540017)

Comment: I like using these loops. Don't have to use `.Offset` if I am referring to multiple columns. Keeps my code shorter and cleaner. On the other hand, why not use an array in that case?

Comment: Because you are working on the sheet, for each criteria you need to hide a row, also you don't need to use Offset either with this loop. Just use `.Cells(Cell.Row, "A")` for example and that's it.

Comment: Yes, but `.Cells(i, 1)` is a little bit shorter :D

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng = .Range("A5:A15")

        For Each cell In rng

            If cell.Value = "" Then

                .Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True

            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This added nothing to the pre-existing answers

Comment: @TimStack some useful tips for OP is how to use the `With Statement`, the `Set` of the range and the `.` before `Rows`.

Comment: So except for the `Set` statement, no new information

Comment: @Tim Stack there are a lot of new things to add. The usage of 'for each' is faster than then 'for i'. The set of the range in a variable help you if clear indicate the ranges and make it easier to add more ranges as OP ask. Also there is no reason to calculate last row when you know the range. More over the code should be as short as you can so avoid declare variables without reason ( start point & last point.). Lastly vbNullString and Is empty may cause issues so is better to use ""

Answer (score 0):

This takes full advantage of the Excel VBA model. I'm guessing it's faster than the above but have not conducted performance tests.

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("A5:A15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next
```

Comment: this works as a treat too. what if i had two separate ranges in above scenario (A5:A15) and (A40:A55) how could i concatenate those two ranges together in above code?

Comment: @accurist Use `Union`, like so:  `For Each Cell In Union(Range("A5:A15"), Range("A40:A55")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

Comment: Or 

For Each Cell In Range("A5:A15,A40:A55").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)